Redis Stack 7.2 Performance Degradation with Load
Scenario

1M JSON documents loaded into Redis Stack (contributing 5GB)
Documents are indexed with multiple keys (1 Text and 3 Tags, 1 Date)
Redis Stack instance is running as "single Pod" (5 GB) in K8 env

Observation

Normal to medium load (up to 100 concurrent users) testing: Response is good
But we are saying performance degradation as load/stress (number of concurrent requests) increase
We did not notice any CPU/Resource constraints around Redis Pod during stress test but performance degrades.

We are in the process of getting exact response delay in milliseconds but degradation is very noticeable
Questions:

Are there any tools that can expose query plans or issues that are causing this delay
Any metrics that Redis Stack exposes that we can easily watch?
I am using Redis Insight but mostly to look at Cache and troubleshooting. Did not explore if it has any additional functionality useful in this case.

What we are looking for:

Identifying what factors are causing Performance degradation
Factors that can improve performance during stress test

Expecting no performance degradation OR at least easily identify factors and ways to improve performance
What we are looking for:

Identifying what factors are causing Performance degradation
Factors that can improve performance during stress test

Timings I took below shows repeatedly crossing 1 sec - for just Id based search on 250K JSON documents:
Normally it takes only single digit milliseconds. Time reported below is just for REDIS Stack call to return JSON document

